# Is cordova available in WL Webview where the url being loaded is a jsp or server side resource

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am loading a jsp or server side application using worklight webview (super.loadUrl("hostname:port/Myapplciation",false)). My question is will cordova related functionality work since its inside WL webview. If it doesn't work what is the actually reason because I had read that WL hybrid application runs inside a webview and cordova works there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

yes, it will work.

(adding some more text to make answer at least 30 chars long so it can be submitted)

Comment: should the Javascript files come from server or can we point it to the files on the devices ?.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a working environment to try it out in, but my suspicion is that getting the JS files from either location should work, but that getting them from the device would be preferred because then you wouldn't have a cache miss and a remote download, and you wouldn't need to host them on the remote server.

Comment: today I tried doing it. I am using an Iframe in the Main WL html file to include my server side jsp/html but when i try to print device.name inside the iframe code doesn't work. I even tried include the script files but it didn't work. I think it works only when I fetch it from the server. So in that case there will be a duplication of javascripts. Please let me know your thoughts